# Drupal hook fired after node created

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

When I create a node I want it to programmatically create some nodes that reference the node just created.

I though I would just need to change form_alter submit function for my form to call a custom function to create the nodes.

Examining the output $form_state I can see that the NID is Null. This would mean to me that my node is created after the submit has been fired. It makes sense. How can I call code to run after the node has been created so that I can automatically create some nodes that reference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use [`hook_nodeapi()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7) and the `insert` handler:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'insert':
      // $node contains the newly created node
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a module that provides what you're looking for. You can find the details here : [Post-save callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308465/post-save-callback)